# Gradient computation with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I would like to compute the gradient of the parameters of a neural network. I wrote I simple toy program, but the gradient is not workig, trhowing instead an error, which I do not understand.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def var_init(n_input, n_output):
    return np.sqrt(6. / (n_input + n_output))

l1_init = var_init(1, 5)

W = tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([1, 5], minval=-l1_init,
                              maxval=l1_init,
                              dtype=tf.float64), name='W')
b = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([5], minval=-l1_init, maxval=l1_init,
                      dtype=tf.float64), name='b')

layer1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(np.matrix([[5.]]), W) + b)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

gr = tf.gradients(layer1,[W,b])

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
sess.run(gr)
```

The error is:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(1, 1), b.shape=(1, 5), m=1, n=5, k=1
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_DOUBLE, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](MatMul/a, W/read)]]
```

Caused by op u'MatMul', defined at:

```
layer1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(np.matrix([[5.]]), W) + b)
```

(I cannot post the whole Traceback because stackoverflow complains that my question is most of all code)

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I've just tried to run your code and all worked as expected.

Comment: Which version of tf and numpy? Thanks

Comment: Tensorflow 1.3.0, Numpy 1.13.1

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I have exactly the same versions. Sorry if I ask some more question: which version of python do you use? and do you use gpu version of tf?

Comment: perfect, issue solved. I had another process running using the gpu. this was the issue. thanks fr your help